# Two JList model not using all data

Tags: java, arrays, swing, sorting, jlist

I have two `JLists` with two models (`inputList` with `inputModel` and `outputList` with `outputModel`) to populate them.

I have a `JButton` with an `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){} listener`

this is the code inside the listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < outputModel.getSize(); i++) {
                if(inputList.isSelectedIndex(i)){
                    inputModel.addElement(outputModel.getElementAt(i));
                    outputModel.remove(i);
                }
            }
            inputList.setModel(sortModel(inputModel));
            outputList.setModel(sortModel(outputModel));
        }
    });
```

the `sortModel(Model m)` method sorts the Strings in the model (using `Arrays.sort()`) and returns a new model that is properly sorted.

Essentially the code is designed to move selected Strings from one JList to another (kind of a available stuff to do --> chosen stuff to do list idea.

The issues is this: However many items I select to transfer, only half of the Strings in the model are transferred ( specifically every items with index 0,2,4,6, etc...)

Why is that?

The sort code is simply this:

```
    private static DefaultListModel<String> sortModel(DefaultListModel<String> model){
    String[] temp = new String[model.getSize()];
    int size = model.getSize();
    if(!model.isEmpty()){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp[i] = model.getElementAt(i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(temp);
        model.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            model.addElement(temp[i]);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < outputModel.getSize(); i++) {
     if(inputList.isSelectedIndex(i)){
         inputModel.addElement(outputModel.getElementAt(i));
         outputModel.remove(i);
     }
}
```

If an object is selected you add it to the inputModel and immediatly remove it from the outputModel which causes the next element `i + 1` to move to the current position `i`. Then the loop increments and thus skips the "next" element, because it is at `i - 1` then.

Maybe you want to write a re-usable utility class for problems like this.

The following code is just an example and you might improve it.

```
public class JLists {

    public static <T> void moveSelection(JList<T> fromList, JList<T> toList) {
        ListSelectionModel fromSelection = fromList.getSelectionModel();
        ListModel<T> fromModel = fromList.getModel();
        ListModel<T> toModel = toList.getModel();
        DefaultListModel<T> newFromModel = createModelCopy(fromModel);
        DefaultListModel<T> newToModel = createModelCopy(toModel);

        int minSelection = fromSelection.getMinSelectionIndex();
        int maxSelection = fromSelection.getMaxSelectionIndex();

        int removedElements = 0;
        for (int i = minSelection; i <= maxSelection; i++) {
            if (fromSelection.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                T elementAt = fromModel.getElementAt(i);
                newToModel.addElement(elementAt);
                newFromModel.removeElementAt(i - removedElements);
                removedElements++;
            }
        }

        fromList.setModel(newFromModel);
        toList.setModel(newToModel);
    }

    private static <T> DefaultListModel<T> createModelCopy(
            ListModel<T> listModel) {
        DefaultListModel<T> newListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listModel.getSize(); i++) {
            T elementAt = listModel.getElementAt(i);
            newListModel.addElement(elementAt);
        }
        return newListModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I just put a i-- after the remove and it works nicely.